# Saving files using code editor - not updating file system in Ubuntu for Windows

Tags: permissions, filesystem, visual-studio-code

I am currently using Visual Studio Code on my Windows 10 machine to edit Terraform files that are pulled/pushed from Ubuntu for Windows.

The problem I face is, whenever I add a new file (rds.tf for example) and save it, it does not update the Ubuntu terminal. Currently, I have to close the Ubuntu terminal and re-open it for the file to appear. The other problem I face is the file permissions are not set. Whilst this is understandable to a degree, it can be frustrating. Please see picture below.

[file permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEC1v.png)

```
---------- 1 chris chris    0 Sep 17 11:48 rds.tf

-rwxrwxrwx 1 chris chris 2609 Sep 17 11:16 variables.tf*

-rwxrwxrwx 1 chris chris 1480 Sep 17 11:16 vpc.tf*
```

It would be helpful if someone could guide me on how to at least update the local file system without having to constantly close the terminal when I have made a change and set file permissions.